# Can this application be embedded in an html file onto my website?

Tags: java

The only thing I didn't write in this is the front and back end of the Calculator inside the constructor of the class panel withing the Calc class.

I also didn't add the components because it would be too long to read.

When I run this is shows up as a JFrame but not the applet viewer in my IDE which it should be running inside.

This code block runs in the applet viewer like it should but that is not the case for my calculator application.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Kyle on 7/17/2017.
 */
public class Kyle extends Applet {
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
    }
}
```

And back to the question...

My imports:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

My class declaration with a nested class declaration and the init, start, stop and destroy methods:

```
public class Calc extends JApplet{

public void init() {
    getContentPane().add(new panel());
}

public void start()
{
    System.out.println("Applet starting");
}

public void stop()
{
    System.out.println("Applet stopping");
}

public void destroy()
{
    System.out.println("Applet destroyed");
}

public class panel extends JPanel
{
    public panel()
    {
    }
}
```

My main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /**
     * Fix in update 1.1
     */

    Comp c = new Comp();
    c.init();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(p);
    frame.setSize(500, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I'm asking because I don't want to pay for hosting if this won't even work as an embedded JApplet application in the browser.

Thank you.

Comment: Applets are dead.

Comment: Applets are deprecated. The Applet plugin is no longer support and in most cases is actively disabled by most browsers - your answer is "technically - yes", "realistically - no"

Comment: Also, applets don't have a `main` method

Comment: Obsolete of course. Technology doesn't die of old age.